# Need someone to tell me the camera preview and picture resolutions in Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I need to know the camera preview and picture resolutions that the Samsung Galaxy S4/S4 Zoom (SM-C101) supports for it's rear camera.

I'm building an application that does real time image processing on the frames received from the camera. By default, the highest resolution is set which makes the processing very slow. So, I want to know what resolutions are available so that I could set a range within which to select from at runtime.

I noticed that some common lower resolutions aren't supported on the S3, so I had to increase the range. So I need to know if I need to change it for the S4.

Someone on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515481/list-of-commonly-supported-camera-picture-sizes) has created an [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atlarge.androidreporter) which records this data and makes it publicly viewable [here](http://www.kirill.org/ar/ar.php). I guess using this would be easier than manually looking up the resolutions.

Comment: I would not close this question. It's mainly asking about the resolutions of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Samsung site](http://www.samsung.com/ae/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/smart-phone/SM-C1010ZKAXSG?subsubtype=android), the rear camera is 16MP with 10x Optical Zoom and enhanced SMART Modes, OIS, 24 - 240mm, F3.1 - F6.3.

You can probably use [this tool](http://web.forret.com/tools/megapixel_aspect.asp?mp=16) to calculate for a rough estimate of image dimensions. *Probably better if somebody with an S4 Zoom can provide actual values*.

```
4000 x 4000 (16,00) - aspect 1:1 (1,00 - square)
4472 x 3576 (15,99) - aspect 5:4 (1,25 - photo)
4512 x 3544 (15,99) - aspect 14:11 (1,27 - photo)
5096 x 3136 (15,98) - aspect 13:8 (1,63 - photo)
4616 x 3464 (15,99) - aspect 4:3 (1,33 - photo)
4736 x 3384 (16,03) - aspect 7:5 (1,40 - photo)
4896 x 3264 (15,98) - aspect 3:2 (1,50 - photo)
```